# JavaScript random quote and authors array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hey, I've gotten stuck with writing a script on Random quotes and authors.
I'm getting 'undefined' messages...huh???
Here's the code I have so far...

```
    <div id="container">
    <div id="quote"> </div>
    <b class="break">//</b><div id="author"> </div>
</div>

<script>
    // set up an array
    var myObj, q, a;
    myObj = [
        { "quote":"Quote 1", "author":"Author 1" },
        { "quote":"Quote 2", "author":"Author 2" },
        { "quote":"Quote 3", "author":"Author 3" },
        { "quote":"Quote 4", "author":"Author 4" },
    ];


    // calculate a random index number
    var arr= [Math.floor((Math.random() * myObj.length-1))];

    // display the Quote
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML=[arr].q;
    document.getElementById("author").innerHTML=[arr].a;

</script>
```

I'm trying to figure out what needs adding or changing.
Any pointers in the right direction would be great!
cheers.

Comment: What are the values of `q` and `a`?

Comment: @CodeF0x - Not really. In fact, the entries of an array in JavaScript **are** properties of an object, and array indexes are property names.

Comment: `[Math.floor((Math.random() * myObj.length-1))]` creates an array with a random numbers, e.g. `[2]`. Then `[arr]` puts that array into another array, so you basically do `[[2]]`. And then you are trying to access the properties `q` and `a` on an array, but arrays don't have such properties (`console.log([].q)`).

Answer (score 2):

Your generation of the random index is wrong in a couple of ways:

1. You're creating an array with the `[...]` bit
2. You don't want `-1` on `length`

Then, you're looking up the entries incorrectly as well, creating a new array and trying to index into it with `arr`.

The property names you're using are also incorrect (`q` and `a` rather than `quote` and `author`).

You might also consider calling `myObj` something like `quotes` since it's an array of quotes.

So:

```
// calculate a random index number
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);

// display the Quote
document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = quotes[index].quote;
document.getElementById("author").innerHTML = quotes[index].author;
```

Live Example:

```js
// set up an array
var quotes = [
    { "quote":"Quote 1", "author":"Author 1" },
    { "quote":"Quote 2", "author":"Author 2" },
    { "quote":"Quote 3", "author":"Author 3" },
    { "quote":"Quote 4", "author":"Author 4" },
];

function showQuote() {
    // calculate a random index number
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);

    // display the Quote
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = quotes[index].quote;
    document.getElementById("author").innerHTML = quotes[index].author;
}

showQuote();
document.getElementById("again").addEventListener("click", showQuote);
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="quote"> </div>
    <b class="break">//</b>
    <div id="author"> </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="again" value="Again">
```

Answer (score 1):

This is completly wrong written, sorry.

Try with:

```
var myObj = [
    { "quote":"Quote 1", "author":"Author 1" },
    { "quote":"Quote 2", "author":"Author 2" },
    { "quote":"Quote 3", "author":"Author 3" },
    { "quote":"Quote 4", "author":"Author 4" },
];

// calculate a random index number
var item = myObj[Math.floor(Math.random() * myObj.length)];

// display the Quote
document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = item.quote;
document.getElementById("author").innerHTML = item.author;
```

Comment: Cause Math.random() is always smaller than 1.

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.random() * myObj.length)` will give an integer number in range of  `<0, length)`

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like:

```
var randomQuote = myObj[Math.floor((Math.random() * myObj.length))]
console.log(randomQuote.quote, randomQuote.author);
```

Comment: yes, you are right, the -1 should be gone (I will edit my answer)

Answer (score -1):

DEMO: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/vrzJjd
You can do it this way:

```
var myObj, q, a;
    myObj = [
        { "quote":"Quote 1", "author":"Author 1" },
        { "quote":"Quote 2", "author":"Author 2" },
        { "quote":"Quote 3", "author":"Author 3" },
        { "quote":"Quote 4", "author":"Author 4" },
    ];


    // calculate a random index number
    var arr= [Math.floor((Math.random() * myObj.length-1))];
    // display the Quote
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML=myObj[arr].quote;
    document.getElementById("author").innerHTML=myObj[arr].author;
```

Comment: `arr` shouldn't be an array (you're using it as an index). `Math.random() * myObj.length-1` makes no sense: Spacing doesn't affect precedence, so this parses as `(Math.random() * myObj.length) - 1`.

Comment: If you're wondering why `myObj[arr]` is working even though you're creating an array, it's because it gets coerced to string, and an array with one number in it coerces to the string version of that number, which is a valid property name for looking up that entry in an array. It's incorrect, but it does function.

Comment: Please consider making your runnable examples **here, on-site**, not off-site. (You could *also* include al ink to the off-site one if you like.) [Here's how to do one.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)